# Convert multiple records to a single record in R

Tags: r, transformation, reshape

So, I know a lot of you will think this question has been asked a lot of times, but I don't think it has. Essentially, I'm looking to completely flatten my data, meaning I want a **single** record for each person. Here is a reproducible example of my data:

```
   id      BusinessUnit var1 var2 var3
1   1 Risk & Compliance    8    7    7
2   1       Investments    7    8    7
3   1      Credit Cards    8    9    7
4   2       Investments    9   10    8
5   2      Credit Cards    9   10    8
6   3 Risk & Compliance    9   10    9
7   3      Credit Cards   10    9   10
8   3       Call Center    6    9   10
9   4       Investments    7    6   10
10  4      Call Centers    7    5    9
11  5 Risk & Compliance   10    7    9
12  6 Risk & Compliance    6    8    9
13  6      Credit Cards    5   10    6
```

What I would like to end up with is something like this:

```
  id     BusinessUnit1 var1_1 var2_1 var3_1 BusinessUnit2 var1_2 var2_2 var3_2
1  1 Risk & Compliance      8      7      7   Investments      7      8      7
2  2       Investments      9     10      8  Credit Cards      9     10      8
  BusinessUnit3 var1_3 var2_3 var3_3
1  Credit Cards      8      9      7
2          <NA>     NA     NA     NA
```

I have tried using the reshape2 package's cast() function, but it wants me to aggregate the data which I don't want to do. Additionally, I don't want a separate record for each Business Unit since that just gets me back to what I already have. Is there a different way to do this that avoids using a for loop?

Comment: What's the max possible number of different business unit ? Can we assume is always 3 or we need to infer it from the data ?

Comment: Good question; the max number of business units is 3, but as you can see above, not everyone has three business units.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a better job for `reshape` than it is for `dcast`. Just add a "time" variable first:

```
mydf$time <- ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), mydf$id, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(mydf, idvar="id", direction = "wide")
#    id    BusinessUnit.1 var1.1 var2.1 var3.1 BusinessUnit.2 var1.2 var2.2 var3.2
# 1   1 Risk & Compliance      8      7      7    Investments      7      8      7
# 4   2       Investments      9     10      8   Credit Cards      9     10      8
# 6   3 Risk & Compliance      9     10      9   Credit Cards     10      9     10
# 9   4       Investments      7      6     10   Call Centers      7      5      9
# 11  5 Risk & Compliance     10      7      9           <NA>     NA     NA     NA
# 12  6 Risk & Compliance      6      8      9   Credit Cards      5     10      6
#    BusinessUnit.3 var1.3 var2.3 var3.3
# 1    Credit Cards      8      9      7
# 4            <NA>     NA     NA     NA
# 6     Call Center      6      9     10
# 9            <NA>     NA     NA     NA
# 11           <NA>     NA     NA     NA
# 12           <NA>     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thank you!